# How to know when batch cloud prediction ends

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am doing an application that receives some data, treats it then creates a prediction-ai batch job. After the predictions are done, I am supposed to take them all and merge them with a previous file. The batch prediction writes to a bucket, let's call is `gs://predictions`.

At the moment, I have a cloud function that gets triggered whenever `gs://predictions` is written to. However, the batch prediction job streams data into the file, updating such file many times when there are lots of predictions to be made. This means that my cloud function gets triggered many times when I just wanted it to be called when the job was finished.

To overcome this, right now the cloud function gets called and then checks whether the job is finished or not. If it is, process the file; if not, let it slide. This, of course, brings a lot of unnecessary processing (and unnecessary code!) :-(

What would really help me here: can the batch job somehow write to Pub/Sub when it is done? Or even better, can it use a webhook so that when it is finished itself calls my cloud function? 
I tried to look into the docs, but could not find anything.

Is there any other proposed solution for this?

Comment: Side question: what's the type of your batch machine type? What's the size of the input and output files (the biggest file in and the biggest file out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [create a log sink into PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create) and filter the logs on this custom filter:

```
resource.type="ml_job"
textPayload="Job completed successfully."
```

Then, when a batch job completed, a log trace is printed and a message is posted into the PubSub topic.

Comment: Yes, I ended up going with that solution :-D. It feels really weird that you can't put a hook for when the job is finished or even set up a PubSub topic to get the warning. Setting up a sink seems like extra work which can bring future issues, but well.

Comment: More efficient tools are coming ;) Stay tuned!

Comment: Did anything change? Are there any better ways to do this now?

Comment: Yes, today eventarc exist and wrap all the complexity and overhead in a few command lines and parameters https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs

Answer (score 0):

Refer to docs [Google Cloud Training job docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#methods)
In order get AI Platform job status ,you can use REST API's provided by GCP ,refer to jobs [AI Platform jobs docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/get)

GET Request body:

```
{
  "jobId": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "startTime": string,
  "endTime": string,
  "state": enum (State),  # This Field is what will tell you status of job
  "errorMessage": string,
  "labels": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "etag": string,

  // Union field input can be only one of the following:
  "trainingInput": {
    object (TrainingInput)
  },
  "predictionInput": {
    object (PredictionInput)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field input.

  // Union field output can be only one of the following:
  "trainingOutput": {
    object (TrainingOutput)
  },
  "predictionOutput": {
    object (PredictionOutput)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field output.
}
```

**State** Field is enum

```
Enums
STATE_UNSPECIFIED   The job state is unspecified.
QUEUED              The job has been just created and processing has not yet begun.
PREPARING           The service is preparing to run the job.
RUNNING             The job is in progress.
SUCCEEDED           The job completed successfully.
FAILED              The job failed. errorMessage should contain the details of the failure.
CANCELLING          The job is being cancelled. errorMessage should describe the reason for the cancellation.
CANCELLED           The job has been cancelled. errorMessage should describe the reason for the cancellation.
```

Note: All this can be done via python or any other language of choice.
[Using Python GCP Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/python-client-library)

Comment: Yes, see, the issue there is: how can you have a cloud function to use the output of such a job? Serverless functions work via trigger, so polling is not really an option there. That would also result in a waste of computation (both time and machinery resources) which makes no sense when that is the exact problem you are trying to address with a serverless design. As I've said it in the question, that was the first approach, which, however, was shown to be inefficient and at times producing false results (i.e the status was not yet updated but the job was finished).